# SQL Date Format Day and Month Mixup

Tags: sql, date

It seems this question is asked a lot, but none of the answers have given me results. I'm pulling my hair out here ... so hopefully someone has an answer.

I have a production server running SQL Server 2005. I backed up the db and restored it on my laptop's SQL Server Express instance. Now date queries are seriously affected. In the prod. server they are all stored as "4/13/2011 12:00:00 AM" format, but on my laptop they are showing as "2011-04-14 00:00:00.000". When I do a query trying to find entries on "4/14/2011" my laptop gives me the error "*The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value*". **Edit**: This exact query runs fine on the production SQL server. (I'm using SSMS to run queries ... not an application/code)

I made sure my laptop's Windows regional settings are the same as the server (English(United States)) and everything on the Region and Language control panel is the exact same.

Finally I ran the following two queries:

```
select name ,alias, dateformat
  from syslanguages
     where langid =
      (select value from master..sysconfigures
         where comment = 'default language')

select @@language
```

Which gave the result of "*us_english, English, mdy*" ..... and "*British*" respectively. Where is this British coming from?! Now when I run this command before my query (in the management studio)

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy
```

Then everything works perfectly! But in the syslanguages query it seems to already be mdy format. I'm not about to rewrite my application with "SET DATEFORMAT" all over the place - so hopefully someone has a clue. Maybe my SQL Express installation is buggared and I have to reinstall it?

I'm going to keep tinkering to hopefully get this to work.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer but another thing to check would be the regional settings of the database, not the server its on. May have decided to use a different 'English' to store the data.

Comment: "When I do a query trying to find entries on" what are you using to do that? SSMS?

Comment: How would you check regional settings of a SQL server database? I can change the collation, but I'm pretty sure that isn't relevant.

Yes - I'm using SSMS (the express edition) to run these queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the language settings of the **login** that you need to change.

You can do it through `SSMS -> Security -> Logins -> YourLogin -> Properties -> Default Language`

Or through TSQL

```
ALTER LOGIN [YourLogin] WITH  DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```

Comment: Yes this was it. I just figured that out. I used SSMS to change it as well. Stupid StackOverflow wouldn't let me answer my own question because I don't have enough rep.

The way to change this in SQL Server Management Studio is to go to the "Security" folder in the root of the SQL Server instance -> "Logins" -> Right-click on a user and "Properties" -> And I set "Default Language" to "English".

Kaboom! Thanks for the help Martin!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify things in `dd-mmm-yyyy` format, or better still, use `DateTime` parameters (rather than varchar input), you won't have a problem.

Try changing the default language to us-english, using the following:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 1033
RECONFIGURE
```

If that doesn't work, you could try language code 0.

Comment: I tried code 0 and it just changed from 0 to 0. No effect on the problem. What do you mean by dd-mmm-yyyy format - isn't that just British?

I can't use parameters because I have a massive legacy application already written, so I don't want to change my queries - just configure my SQL Server to be the same.

Comment: If you declare dates as '16-Apr-2011' or '2011-04-16' it's unambiguous, and SQL server will always do the right thing.  But really you shouldn't be concatenating date strings into your SQL, you should be using parameters and passing datetime information like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing dates as string literals - or concatenating strings to build up the sql in your application?

If you are doing this, consider using parameters for the dateTime data types. Or at least escape them using the ODBC escape clause and format them as in { ts'yyyy-mm-ddhh:mm:ss[.fff] '} such as: { ts'1998-09-24 10:02:20' }.

It is most probably your application not passing the datetime properly.

Comment: Concat strings in the application. But I don't think that is the problem because I'm running these queries straight into SQL Server Management Studio.

I've never seen that escape clause format before ... I'll read up a bit more about it.